# Python: cerberus check_with function

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, cerberus

I would like to validate a `dict`, where the values adhere to the following rules:

- value must be either a single `float` or `List(float)`
- if it is a single `float`, the value must be 1
- if it's a `List(float)`, each float must be positive

Here's my code and some test assertions, which are working properly:

```
import cerberus

v = cerberus.Validator()

schema1 = {
    "key1": {
        "type": ["float", "list"],
        "min": 1,
        "max": 1,
        "schema": {"type": "float", "min": 0},
    }
}
document1 = {"key1": 1}
document2 = {"key1": 5}
document3 = {"key1": "5"}
document4 = {"key1": [0.5, 0.3]}
document5 = {"key1": ["0.5", 0.3]}

assert v.validate(document1, schema1)
assert not v.validate(document2, schema1)
assert not v.validate(document3, schema1)
assert v.validate(document4, schema1)
assert not v.validate(document5, schema1)
```

Now, I have to implement one more condition:

- if it's a `List(float)`, the `sum` of `float` must equal 1

Therefore, I wrote a `check_with` function as described in the docs (https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html).

```
from cerberus import Validator

class MyValidator(Validator):
    def _check_with_sum_eq_one(self, field, value):
        """Checks if sum equals 1"""

        if sum(value) != 1:
            self._error(field, f"Sum of '{field}' must exactly equal 1")
```

The adjusted schema and test documents look like this:

```
v = MyValidator()

schema2 = {
    "key1": {
        "type": ["float", "list"],
        "min": 1,
        "max": 1,
        "schema": {"type": "float", "min": 0, "max": 1, "check_with": "sum_eq_one"},
    }
}

document1 = {"key1": 1}
document2 = {"key1": 5}
document3 = {"key1": "5"}
document4 = {"key1": [0.5, 0.3]}  # error
document5 = {"key1": ["0.5", 0.3]}  # error
document6 = {"key1": [0.5, 0.5]}  # error
```

Now, whenever the value is a `List(float)`, only the first element of the `list` will be injected into my function, leading to an `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.
When validating `document4`, `field` will be `int=0` and `value=0.5`. So the error message makes sense.

I am wondering, why the whole list is not passed to my function? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try to catch the error and only continue your function, if the error was occurred? For example like in this manner:

```
class MyValidator(Validator):

def _check_with_sum_eq_one(self, field, value):
    """ Checks whether value is a list and its sum equals 1.0. """
    if isinstance(value, list) and sum(value) != 1.0:
        self._error(str(value), f"Sum of '{field}' must exactly equal 1")


schema2 = {
    "key1": {
        "type": ["list", "float"],
        "min": 1,
        "max": 1,
        "schema": {"type": "float", "min": 0, "max": 1},
        "check_with": "sum_eq_one",
    }
}

v = MyValidator(schema2)

document1 = {"key1": 1}
document2 = {"key1": 5}
document3 = {"key1": "5"}
document4 = {"key1": [0.3, 0.5]}  # error
document5 = {"key1": ["0.5", 0.3]}  # error
#document6 = {"key1": [0.5, 0.5]}  # error
assert v.validate(document1)
assert not v.validate(document2)
assert not v.validate(document3)
assert v.validate(document4)
assert not v.validate(document5)
```

Comment: This is working. You can safely replace `self._drop_remaining_rules` with `return`.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is working properly. However, in my view it's overly complicated.

First, adjust `schema2` as follows:

```
schema2 = {
    "key1": {
        "type": ["float", "list"],
        "min": 0,
        "max": 1,
        "check_with": "sum_eq_one"
    }
}
```

Next, adjust `_check_with_sum_eq_one` as follows:

```
class MyValidator(Validator):
    def _check_with_sum_eq_one(self, field, value):
        """Checks if sum equals 1"""

        if (isinstance(value, float) or isinstance(value, int)) and value != 1:
            self._error(field, f"Sum of '{field}' must exactly equal 1")
        if isinstance(value, list):
            if all([isinstance(x, float) for x in value]):
                if sum(value) != 1:
                    self._error(field, f"Sum of '{field}' must exactly equal 1")
            else:
                self._error(field, f"All list members must be of type ['float']")
```

Finally, assert that everything works as expected.

```
v = MyValidator()

document1 = {"key1": 1}
document2 = {"key1": 5}
document3 = {"key1": "5"}
document4 = {"key1": [0.5, 0.3]}
document5 = {"key1": ["0.5", 0.3]}
document6 = {"key1": [0.5, 0.5]}

assert v.validate(document1, schema2)
assert not v.validate(document2, schema2)
assert not v.validate(document3, schema2)
assert not v.validate(document4, schema2)
assert not v.validate(document5, schema2)
assert v.validate(document6, schema2)
```

What I don't like here is the fact that I need to check 'manually' if all list members are of type `float` (`if all([isinstance(x, float) for x in value])`). In my view, this test belongs into `schema2`. However, I didn't succeed in adjusting `schema2` in a way, that the test for being of type `float` precedes the `check_with` validation.

Any hints for further simplifying this task will be appreciated.